# How to write portable code given lex/ flex code incompatibilities

Tags: portability, lex, flex-lexer

Flex is somewhat a free implementation of Lex program, although there are some incompatibilities between them.

For instance Lex store the current line into a global variable `yylineno`  whereas in flex to access it you should add in the code `%option yylineno` .

Is possible to write portable code knowing that  `%option`  tag is not recognized by Lex?
**Update :**

lex: Software Generation Utilities (SGU) Solaris-ELF (4.0)

flex version 2.5.2

Comment: Please precise your Lex & Flex versions.

Comment: lex: Software Generation Utilities (SGU) Solaris-ELF (4.0)

Comment: From my perspective (Next to nothing experience in Solaris, I played a little around with Solaris Express Develper Edition and OpenSolaris back in 2007), I'm afraid Solaris Lex is not in the mainstream. Please edit accordingly your question to help people answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost found the solution in this case, According To this [link](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/flex/flex_20.html), to activate the global variable **yylineno** you should add **-l** option when executing flex so you don't have to add the **%option** in the code,so you will have a compatible code between flex and lex .